# How to pass a variable from a function to a class python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to pass a variable from a function to a class. Example code is below:

```
def hello(var):

    return var

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def value(self):
        print var

hello(var)
test = test()
test.value()
```

I would like to pass `var` into the class `test()`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040998/how-to-change-variables-in-python ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify your class like this:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def value(self):
        print self.var

test_inst = test(var)
test_inst.value()
```

Also, you cannot use the same exact name to refer to both class instance and a class itself.

Comment: @SilentGhost -- I used this code but I got the error -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "function_pass.py", line 41, in <module>
    test_inst = test()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @chriss: I didn't suggest to use `test()`, I suggested to use `test(var)`

Comment: That says that the global `var` is not defined when I do that.

Comment: @chriss: well, why is it not defined? where does come from in your code?

Comment: I can define it. And it works. It's when I pass it in via the command line the problem starts. It won't accept it then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self._var = var

    def value(self):
        print self._var
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the statement:

```
global var
```

to your code:

```
>>> global var
>>> def hello():
       print var

>>> class test():
       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def value(self):
           print var

>>> var = 15
>>> hello()
15
>>> test().value()
15
```

Cue standard disclaimer regarding global variables are bad... but this is how you do it.

Comment: that's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, totally unnecessary, but given his code, this is what I *think* he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call hello function in class's function.

```
def hello (var):
    return var

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def value(self):
        var = hello(5)
        print var

test = test()
test.value()
```